# Mysql query gives wrong data

Tags: php, mysqli

```
select * from stock where product_name like '".$searchType."%' or product_brand like '".$searchType."%' or type like '".$searchType."%' and (price between ".$min_price." and ".$max_price.") group by product_name
```

I have table having name `stock` where I have column `product_name`, `product_brand`, `type` and `price`. Now, I have a price range slider where its work only for `type` but not working for `product_name` and `product_brand`. For example.

When I slide price slider and its range is upto 200 to 500 and select `type` then it show result if `type` is not in range it show `result not found`. But in case of `product_name` and `product_brand` it always show data while it is on price range or not.

So, How can I fix this issue? Please help me.

Thnak You

Comment: You will probably need brackets around all of the OR conditions, otherwise if any match it will select that row - than AND this bracketed condition with the range.

Comment: what is the use of group by in the statement?

Comment: remove duplicate data @Rafee

Comment: but why have you got duplicate data? Better keep your data clean than fudge the issue by hiding it in your queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to group the OR conditions in your SELECT otherwise as soon as one matches it will stop checking any other conditions...

```
select * 
  from stock where ( product_name like '".$searchType."%' or 
      product_brand like '".$searchType."%' or 
      type like '".$searchType."%') and 
     (price between ".$min_price." and ".$max_price.") 
  group by product_name
```

You should also look into prepared statements as this solves various other problems (include SQL injections and rogue quotes in your search terms).

Answer (score -3):

The query which you created which has many loops. That's why the results are overloading. I can't give exact solution because database is not with me. But try to use left join and reduce the loops.